Streamlit nut running and gives connection error
When I run the file I get the :
Connection error
Is Streamlit still running? If you accidentally stopped Streamlit, just restart it in your terminal:
streamlit run yourscript.py
I could not solve it even I used perist_directory:
persist_directory = r"C:\Users\bbb\OneDrive\Documents\RadicalAI\quizify\mission-quizify\tasks\task_8\chroma_db"
sys.path.append(persist_directory)
